# Plotting power curve with power on y-axis, effect size on x-axis, sample size held constant

Tags: statistical-power

I'm performing a multivariate power analysis on episode-level medical data to estimate the minimum average cost reduction we can detect with an 80% positive identification rate (i.e., power  = 0.80) among patients who would be participating in a cost savings program. From this we'll assess whether it's worth our time and effort to continue the program.

To be clear, the sample size has already been determined (namely, all of the records for providers participating in our cost savings program, plus records from non-participating providers as the control cohort). Therefore, rather than plotting a traditional power curve with power on the y-axis and # of observations on the x-axis, I'm going to plot power on the y-axis and hypothetical effect sizes (% cost savings) on the x-axis.

The game plan is to pull twenty bootstrapped samples from the baseline (period=0) episode data to simulate future (period=1) patient episodes from the same population. Among those hypothetical patients in the treatment cohort in period=1, their medical cost values will be multiplied by the hypothetical cost savings effect size (-0.5%, -1.0%, -1.5%, etc.). Following exact matching on key variables, a difference-in-differences regression analysis will then be performed on each bootstrapped sample and the p-value on the (cohort)x(period) coefficient will be recorded. The power = 0.80 threshold will be observed where at least 80% of the (cohort)x(period) coefficients are statistically significant.

Is this a statistically valid approach? I'm aware that normally Monte Carlo simulations are implemented. However given the complex nature of my data I thought bootstrapping was a better solution.

Comment: Leaving other issues to one side for the moment -- imagine you really had power of 0.8; with only 20 simulated samples you have a 37% chance of observing less than 80% power in your simulation. To me 20 seems way on the low side (typically for power-simulations I tend to regard ten thousand as somewhat on the small side, but many people seem to happily get by with a couple of thousand).

Comment: @Glen_b You're right, the small sample size for my bootstraps is an issue. My dataframe is fairly large, 1.9 million records, and considering I have to run 20 bootstraps per increment of cost savings effect size the number of computations are quite large (and I'm sharing memory on the RStudio server with other users). There are parallel functions in R I could look into.

Comment: @Glen_b If my math is correct, with 20 bootstrap iterations, if I correctly reject the null H0 = No cost savings for 80% (16) of the 20 bootstrap samples, the 95% CI for the true power is 0.80 +/- 0.175.